# Two or more BroadcastReceivers with same Priority

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

According to this [article](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1151) when two or more `BroadcastReceiver` have the same priority the order in which they receiver an **ordered intent** is **arbitrary**.

However from my observation the order in which `BroadcastReceiver` have received the ordered intents was anything but arbitrary. Certain applications (for example Handcent SMS) have always been the first to receive the ordered intent.
So are there any other **criteria** upon which a `BroadcastReceiver` is prioritized in favor of other ones with the same priority ? Or are there some techniques for prioritizing some `BroadcastReceiver` over others ?

Comment: I have written handcent and asked how they do this since they broke my app!

Comment: Been a few weeks no reply, I don't think they are going too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience first installed application will be first served with the broadcast. I've verified that on Samsung Galaxy S with Android 2.2.1, HTC Desire HD with Android 2.2.3, and emulator.

Comment: Exactly. The first installed will be served first.

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work according to the guidelines.  That's not how it works though.  Try apps like Handcent, GO SMS, and vzw messages and see if your app works?  nope.